# Create derived struct from base

Tags: c++

I have a POD struct from a library with many data fields:

```
struct A {
    int foo1;
    float foo2;
    ...
};
```

Now I would like to extend it to add some custom data and thought of this:

```
struct B : public A {
    int bar1;
    bool bar2;
};
```

What is a good way to create an instance of `B` from an instance of `A`? This does not work:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit: removed the suggestion to add a constructor `B(A const &)`, OP's update suggests that the given structs should not be modified.)

You can create a `B` and then use the compiler-generated `A::operator=(A&)`:

```
A a = { whatever };
B b = { whatever };
static_cast<A &>(b) = a;
```

Comment: Trouble is the POD-ness is lost ;-(. As well as the default constructor.

Comment: Second version keeps POD-ness (but doesn't allow the initialization form)

Comment: @Deduplicator "standard layout" is the new POD, and adding the ctor does not make B non-standard layout.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Adding the ctor removes the default ctor, making it non-trivial and thus non-POD. Anyway, does not matter anymore. POD and standard layout are still distinct.

Comment: @Deduplicator You are right, POD still exists in C++11, and POD and standard layout are distinct (my fault). I thought that maybe the OP wrote POD but could live with a standard layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on inheritance, beginning with an A would work.
There's no change in memory-layout.

With inheritance, do it in two steps:

1. Create derived: `B b;`

   - Instead with 0-init: `B b = {0};`
2. Copy all members: `(A&)b = a`.

The compiler should be able to optimize that.

Anyway, if possible start with the derived instead of copying.

Comment: @Both: Sorry, mislaid my cast. Corrected.

Comment: Surely a C++-style cast is preferred

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Only where there is at least a slight chance for doing the wrong cast. Does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Make struct B contain a member of type A.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast` may only be used if the base has a virtual function